# Snakemake Using expand with dictionary

Tags: expand, snakemake

I am writing this rule:

```
rule process_files:
    input: 
        dataout=expand("{{dataset}}/{{sample}}.{{ref}}.{{state}}.{{case}}.myresult.{name}.tsv", name=my_list[wildcards.ref]) 
    output:
        "{dataset}/{sample}.{ref}.{state}.{case}.endresult.tsv"
    shell:
        do something ...
```

Were `expand` will get value from dictionary `my_dictionary` based on the `ref` value. I used `wildcards` like this `my_dictionary[wildcards.ref]`. But it ends up with this error `name 'wildcards' is not defined`

`my_dictionary` something like:
`{A:[1,2,3], B:[s1,s2..].....}`

I could use

```
def myfun(wildcards):
    return expand("{{dataset}}/{{sample}}.{{ref}}.{{state}}.{{case}}.myresult.{name}.tsv", name=my_dictionary[wildcards.ref])
```

and use `myfun` as input , but this does not answer why I can not use expand in place directly

Any suggestion how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question seems similar to [snakemake wildcards or expand command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45508579/snakemake-wildcards-or-expand-command) and the bottom line is that `wildcards` is not defined in the input. So your solution of using an input function (or a lambda function) seems correct.

(As to *why* `wildcards` is not defined in input, I don't know...)

Comment: Thanks, The function worked but it did not resolve the variable between double curly braces  so it will ask for input for `{dataset}/{sample}.{ref}.{state}.{case}`and raise an error.

Answer (score 2):

As @dariober mentioned there is the `wildcards` objects but this is only accesible in the run/shell portion but can be accessed using an input function in `input`.

Here is an example implementation that will expand the input based on the `wildcards.ref`:

```
rule all:
    input: expand("{dataset}/{sample}.{ref}.{state}.{case}.endresult.tsv", dataset=["D1", "D2"], sample=["S1", "S2"], ref=["R1", "R2"], state=["STATE1", "STATE2"], case=["C1", "C2"])


my_list = {"R1": [1, 2, 3], "R2": ["s1", "s2"]}

rule process_files:
    input:
        lambda wildcards: expand(
            "{{dataset}}/{{sample}}.{{ref}}.{{state}}.{{case}}.myresult.{name}.tsv", name=my_list[wildcards.ref])
    output:
        "{dataset}/{sample}.{ref}.{state}.{case}.endresult.tsv"
    shell:
        "echo '{input}' > {output}"
```

If you implement it as the `lambda` function example above, it should resolve the issue you mention:

> The function worked but it did not resolve the variable between double curly braces so it will ask for input for {dataset}/{sample}.{ref}.{state}.{case}and raise an error.

Comment: Actually my function is the same as your lambda function and raises this error. def `myfun(wildcards):
    return expand("{{dataset}}/{{sample}}.{{ref}}.{{state}}.{{case}}.myresult.{name}.tsv", name=my_list[wildcards.ref])` . to overcome the issue I need to resolve each var for example `ref` . would be `wildcards.ref`` and so on.

Comment: There should not really be need to do that.  You are saying you pass to expand, in the case of `{dataset}`, `dataset = wildcards.dataset`?  Seems redundant. I am using snakemake 5.3.0 in the example and it works using your `myfun` or lambda.

Comment: The issue is after using expand; the variable passed to `sample` is `{sample}` so it would be `sample={sample}` not the actual value of sample, which makes problem in processing for next step because now there is nothing called `{dataset}/{sample...}` in the input file

Comment: I am sorry but I cannot seem to reproduce this issue you are mentioning.  Could you maybe edit your question and provide example of what an input would look like for one input wildcard combination? Either I am misunderstanding what are you trying to do or our implementations are different? You want to have a single value for all the wildcards except `name`?  Essentially group a set of `name` inputs together? In that case you should have `{sample}` in the result of expand as that wildcard will be deduced from `rule all` and output.