# Is there a way to create a snakemake rule dynamically?

Tags: python, dynamic-programming, snakemake

Suppose I want to create many rules, identical in every way, apart from some input parameters. Is there a way to create a function that would allow me to create a snakemake rule dynamically, while supplying these different input parameters everytime?

It would look something like this for example:

```
from snakemake import Rule, expand

def create_rule(rule_name, input_param):
    input_file = f"data/{input_param}.txt"
    output_file = f"results/{rule_name}_{input_param}.txt"
    rule_input = input(input_file)
    rule_output = output(output_file)
    rule_script = "my_script.py"
    rule_shell = f"python {rule_script} {input_file} {output_file}"
    return Rule(
        name=rule_name,
        input=rule_input,
        output=rule_output,
        shell=rule_shell
    )
```

This is what I am trying to do in my own code:

```
fit_result_variation = lambda **kwargs: expand(rules.average_results.output, **modified_configuration(default_config, **kwargs))

variations = dict(
    a = np.arange(5,15,1),
    b = np.arange(5,25,1),
    c = [2,3,4,5],
)

for var_name, var_values in variations.items():
    rule_name = f"{var_name}_syst"
    rule_input = fit_result_variation(**{var_name: var_values})
    rule_output = expand(transient(f"{rule_name}_{{value}}.json", value=var_values))
    rule_run = """
        for input_file, output_file in zip(input, output):
            os.symlink(input_file, output_file)
    """
    globals()[rule_name] = rule(rule_name, input=rule_input, output=rule_output, run=rule_run)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also nest a rule directive inside a for loop (or if statement).  Not sure this solves exactly what you need, but something like:

```
fit_result_variation = lambda **kwargs: expand(rules.average_results.output, **modified_configuration(default_config, **kwargs))

variations = dict(
    a = np.arange(5,15,1),
    b = np.arange(5,25,1),
    c = [2,3,4,5],
)

for var_name, var_values in variations.items():
    rule:
        name: f"{var_name}_syst"
        input: fit_result_variation(**{var_name: var_values})
        output: expand(transient(f"{var_name}_syst_{{value}}.json", value=var_values))
        run:
            for input_file, output_file in zip(input, output):
                os.symlink(input_file, output_file)
```

Much cleaner and easier than making rule objects.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by passing input parameters, By using the Rule() class from Snakemake package to generate a rule and set the input, output, and shell commands according to the input parameters.

Checkout this example based on the one you gave:

```
from snakemake import Rule
from snakemake.shell import shell

def create_rule(rule_name, input_param):
    input_file = get_input_file(input_param)
    output_file = get_output_file(rule_name, input_param)
    shell_cmd = get_shell_cmd(input_file, output_file)
    return Rule(
        name=rule_name,
        input=input(input_file),
        output=output(output_file),
        shell=shell_cmd
    )

def get_input_file(input_param):
    return f"data/{input_param}.txt"

def get_output_file(rule_name, input_param):
    return f"results/{rule_name}_{input_param}.txt"

def get_shell_cmd(input_file, output_file):
    rule_script = "my_script.py"
    return shell(
        "python {script} {input} {output}",
        script=rule_script,
        input=input_file,
        output=output_file
    )
```

After that you call this method to generate rules based on your input, and
Because this function only creates Snakemake rules, You can save the rules in a list or dictionary and add them to your workflow file using a loop or similar method, somthing like this:

```
    from snakemake import Workflow

    # List of input parameters
    input_params = ["file1", "file2", "file3"]

    # List of rule names
    rule_names = ["rule1", "rule2", "rule3"]

    # Generate a list of Snakemake rules using create_rule()
    rules = [create_rule(rule_name, input_param) for rule_name, input_param in zip(rule_names, input_params)]

    # Create a Snakemake workflow using the rules
    workflow = Workflow(rules=rules)

    # Write the workflow to a Snakefile
    workflow.write_snakefile("Snakefile")
```