# Snakemake - how do I input a range of different files delineated from each other numerically?

Tags: python, snakemake

This seems like a basic question but I keep getting some variation of the error: `No values given for wildcard`.

I have a group of 22 files named `Ne-sQTL_perind.counts.gz.qqnorm_chr{#}.gz`. I would like to act on them in a rule. What I have originally looks like this:

```
rule QTLtools_filter:
    input:
        file=expand("Ne-sQTL_perind.counts.gz.qqnorm_chr{i}.gz",i=range(1,22)),
        chk=".prepare_phen_table.chkpnt"
    output:
        expand("{input.file}.qtltools")
    message:
        "Making phenotype files QTLtools compatible..."
    shell:
        "cat {input.file} | awk '{ $4=$4\" . +\"; print $0 }' | tr " " \"\t\" | bgzip -c > {input.file}.qtltools"
```

However, I get the `No values found for wildcare 'input'`, which is confusing to me, because in the docs, [we have a clear example of this working with the wildcare `replicates`](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial/basics.html?highlight=lines#step-5-calling-genomic-variants). How do I expand this wildcard such that it includes all files numbered between 1-22? I've also tried defining a function to do this for me at the suggestion of [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45508579/snakemake-wildcards-or-expand-command) to no avail; still same error message.

```
def expandChromo(wildcards):
    return expand("Ne-sQTL_perind.counts.gz.qqnorm_chr{i}.gz",i=range(1,22))
...
rule QTLtools_filter:
    input:
        expandChromo,
        chk=".prepare_phen_table.chkpnt"
    output:
        expand("{wildcards.expandChromo}.qtltools")
    message:
        "Making phenotype files QTLtools compatible..."
    shell:
        "cat {wildcards.expandChromo} | awk '{ $4=$4\" . +\"; print $0 }' | tr " " \"\t\" | bgzip -c > {wildcards.expandChromo}.qtltools"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have 2 rules. The first one (let's call it `all`) has no output but clearly states what do you want to get as the result of your pipeline:

```
rule all:
    input: expand("Ne-sQTL_perind.counts.gz.qqnorm_chr{i}.gz.qtltools", i=range(1,22))
```

This would give Snakemake an idea of your 22 target files.

Now you can teach Snakemake to create those files:

```
rule QTLtools_filter:
    input:
        "{file}.gz"
    output:
        "{file}.gz.qtltools"
    message:
        "Making phenotype files QTLtools compatible..."
    shell:
        "cat {input} | awk '{ $4=$4\" . +\"; print $0 }' | tr " " \"\t\" | bgzip -c > {input}.qtltools"
```

Note that this rule takes a single file as an input and single file as an output, and the wildcard allows Snakemake to match this pair for each `i` in your range. I didn't find any reason for setting `chk=".prepare_phen_table.chkpnt"` as an input, but this is something you may add if needed.

Comment: Thank you! Where is `{file}` defined?

Comment: @CelineDion `{file}` is not defined, it is a wildcard. When Snakemake finds that it needs a particular file, it starts looking for the patterns in the `output` sections of the rules that match the filename exactly. When it finds one (and if there is not ambiguity) it derives the value of each wildcard to fulfill the requirement.